# find the eigenvectors of the eigenvalue 1 - simple question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

simple question but I seem to be having difficulties.

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & \gamma & 4\\0 & 2 & \beta \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, find the eigenvectors of the eigenvalue 1.

What I did:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & \gamma & 4\\0 & 2 & \beta \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x+\gamma y+4z \\ 2y+\beta z \\ z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$

So...

1) $x+\gamma y +4z = x$

2) $2y+\beta z = y$

3) $z=z$

From 1) we get that $y=\frac{-4}{\gamma}z$ but from 2) we get that $y = -\beta z$ so we overall we get that $\beta = \frac{4}{\gamma}$ (suppose that z is not 0, if z=0 then the eigenvector is 1,0,0, but if z is not 0, the result gets very complex) but how can that be? We don't know anything about beta or gamma and we can't say anything about them. we can't impose restrictions on them or anything like that. I don't know how to interpet this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system can be reduced to 
$$
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    y+\beta z & =& 0, \\
    (\beta\gamma-4)z &=& 0.
  \end{array}
  \right.
$$
If $\beta\gamma \neq 4$ then $z=y=0$ and $x \in \mathbb{F}$. So, the eigenvectors are of the form $c\cdot(1,0,0)^T$, $c \in \mathbb{F}$. If $\beta\gamma = 4$ then system reduces to $y+\beta z = 0$ that implies $y=-\beta z$ ($x,z \in \mathbb{F}$). And the eigenvectors are of the form $c_1\cdot(1,0,0)^T+c_2\cdot(0,-\beta,1)^T$, $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{F}$.